# debugging a logic error in a module

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm having trouble with an assignment in my book.  I'm writing a super simple application that converts fahrenheit to celcius and vice versa.  Everything works perfectly, except that the module I wrote to convert fahrenheit to celcius keeps returning a zero.  I can't figure it out, I've been on debug in Eclipse, stepping through each step, and I can't figure out what is wrong with my f>c conversion  equation, or what else it could be.  Can anyone more experienced than me see the problem?  I'd really appreciate a look-over.  Thanks so much!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TemperatureConversions 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String initialType;
        double fahrenheit = 1;
        double celcius = 1;
        System.out.print("Would you like to enter a fahrenheit or celcius temperature for conversion? (f/c):  ");
        initialType = input.next();
        switch ( initialType )
        {
            case "f":
                System.out.printf("Please input fahrenheit temperature:  ");
                fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
                celcius = celcius (fahrenheit);
                System.out.print("\n" + fahrenheit + "f converted to celcius is " +celcius + "c");
                break;
            case "c":
                System.out.printf("Please input celcius temperature:  ");
                celcius = input.nextInt();
                fahrenheit = fahrenheit (celcius);
                System.out.print("\n" + celcius + "c converted to fahrenheit is " + fahrenheit + "f");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.printf("%s is an invalid input.  Please try again, and only input either 'f' or 'c'");
                break;
        }
        System.out.printf("\nAdios Turd Nuggets");
    }

    public static double celcius(double f)
    {
        double c = 5 / 9 * (f - 32);
        return c;
    }

    public static double fahrenheit(double c)
    {
        double f = c * 1.8 + 32;
        return f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is with the expression `5 / 9`. If you divide two integers, the result is also integer and in this case it's 0. Try `5.0 / 9.0 * (f - 32)`

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try that.

Comment: If it works, please accept this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers